# Can not save user settings in Redmine 1.2

Tags: redmine

After upgrading Redmine to 1.2 I can not save email notification and language settings on "My account" page. 
I ran rake migrate, but that did not helped. 
What can cause that problem and is there any way to fix it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save your configuration, you can simply save the "email.yml" file (for email configuration) and "database.yml" (for database configuration).

These files are situated on :

```
<your_redmine_installation>/configuration/
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I can send test email from Administration->Settings, but on user page I can't save neither language settings nor email-notification settings. Is it problem with configuration files or with database?